# Ionic 3 - Defer file download until folder created

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, angular-promise

I'm working on an app where it needs to download the files to custom folder in the mobile. Here's the code I've used,

```
downloadImage(imageURL) {

    file.createDir(this.storageDirectory, 'FolderName', false);

    const fileTransfer: FileTransferObject = this.transfer.create();          
    const imageName = imageURL.split('/').pop();

    fileTransfer.download(imageURL, this.storageDirectory + 'FolderName/' + imageName).then((entry) => {
        const alertSuccess = this.alertCtrl.create({
            title: `Download Succeeded!`,
            subTitle: `${imageURL} was successfully downloaded to: ${entry.toURL()}`,
            buttons: ['Ok']
        });
        alertSuccess.present();
    }, (error) => {
        console.log(error)
        const alertFailure = this.alertCtrl.create({
            title: `Download Failed!`,
            subTitle: `${imageURL} was not successfully downloaded. Error code: ${error.code}`,
            buttons: ['Ok']
        });
        alertFailure.present();
    });
}
```

Based on some references, I tried to use promise like this.

```
downloadImage(imageURL) {
  var folderName = 'FolderName';
  this.createDirectory(folderName);
  console.log('After CreateDirectory');
  this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      const fileTransfer: FileTransferObject = this.transfer.create();        
      const imageName = imageURL.split('/').pop();

      fileTransfer.download(imageURL, this.storageDirectory + 'FolderName/' + imageName).then((entry) => {
          const alertSuccess = this.alertCtrl.create({
              title: `Download Succeeded!`,
              subTitle: `${imageURL} was successfully downloaded to: ${entry.toURL()}`,
              buttons: ['Ok']
          });
          alertSuccess.present();
      }, (error) => {
          console.log(error)
          const alertFailure = this.alertCtrl.create({
              title: `Download Failed!`,
              subTitle: `${imageURL} was not successfully downloaded. Error code: ${error.code}`,
              buttons: ['Ok']
          });
          alertFailure.present();
      });
  });
}

createDirectory(folderName): Promise<Boolean> {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('createDirectory = ' + folderName)
    }, 5000);

    if(!this.platform.is('cordova')) {
      return false;
    }

    if (this.platform.is('ios')) {
      this.storageDirectory = this.file.externalRootDirectory;
    }
    else if(this.platform.is('android')) {
      this.storageDirectory = this.file.externalRootDirectory;
    }
    else {
      return false;
    }

    this.file.createDir(this.storageDirectory, folderName, false)
    .then((success) => {
      resolve(true);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      reject(false);
    });
  });
}
```

When I click on the link which triggers this function, it shows a popup like "Allow MyApp to access photos, media...", but before the user press "Allow" button, it's displaying the error popup. I tried keeping this inside the async block, but still I'm facing the same issue.

How to defer the flow until the user confirms the popup? Any help on this would be much appreciated.

Comment: Not sure what triggers this popup, but createDirectory() returns a promise, and you completely ignore it. It should be `this.createDirectory().then(() => doSomethingNowThatTheDirectoryHasBeenCreated())`. You need to learn about promise chaining, because you using promise antipatterns.

Comment: @JBNizet I tried like that as you said, it is throwing an error when I click the "Allow" button in popup, it throws error "ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): false". This is happening only when the folder exits

Comment: So you have your answer. You shouldn't try to create the directory if it already exists.

Comment: @JBNizet I tried resolving the promise, if the directory exists. It passed that. Thanks.

Comment: Here is an example showing how bad an idea it is calling an overridable method from a constructor in Java: https://gist.github.com/jnizet/bbea3b4072329cd7540d8c2a32fc7244

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks, I'll take a look and learn that. I appreciate your valuable time..